# Redirect user to Hebrew Wikipedia if no such article exists in my personal MediaWiki website

Tags: html, css, mediawiki, right-to-left, wiki

I wish to create a Wiki syntax template that will redirect a user to Hebrew Wikipedia if no such **linked** article exists in my personal MediaWiki website.

### I tried this code

#### Template body:

```
<a href="https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{urlencode:{{{1}}}|PATH}}">{{{1}}}</a><noinclude>
[[category:דוגמה]]
</noinclude>
```

#### Template call (example):

```
{{העברה|קרח (כימיה)}}
```

The template seems to work but it's output is very messy:

```
<a href="https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%97%20%28%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94">קרח (כימיה</a>
```

How to prevent the output from being messy?

Comment: Non-latin links to Wikipedia are alway messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{urlencode:{{{1}}}|PATH}}">{{{1}}}</a>
```

? See details at https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Help:Magic_words#URL_data

Comment: Dear @sorawee, sorry, my bad; I double checked with another link and it works fine (full valid redirect) --- the only problem is that the output is messy, please see updated question. Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Encode / Decode URL**

I think you can use Special characters for languages and make the currect URL:
https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%97_%28%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%29

You can use this site: https://www.webatic.com/url-convertor
And write hebrew words and get code for URL.
[image]

Comment: Links should be created automatically from template --- I shouldn't encode anything... Thanks,